# OpenID login (steam) with AngularJS, socket.io and node.js using JWT

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

I am wondering what is the safe way to login using OpenID in my AngularJS app, with a Node.js backend and socket.io for the real-time.

The thing is that OpenID forces me to use a new window for the redirection dance, so my setup is:

1. Angularjs renders a view with a button. (this remains open)
2. The button opens a new window and loads my backend, /auth/openid/
   where I set the afterlogin url and redirect to openid site
3. The openid site redirects to my afterlogin backend
   /auth/afteropenid/ where I handle the user data and create a
   JsonWebToken.

My problem is that I dont really know what is the best way to continue.
I have to send somehow the JWT to the AngularJS.

One of the ways I see is passing in the query to AngularJS, here I could do everything in the same window, angular > openidsite > angular(with token in querystring). I would configure AngularJS to handle a route and work with the token. I dont know how safe if this, putting the JWT in the querystring seems like a bad idea.

The other way I see is using socket.io, my app already uses this, I am not including it just for the openID login.

1. When I open the new window, I put the ID of the open socket,
   /auth/openid?socketID=XXXXXX
2. Then, after the openID site redirects back to the backend, 
   /auth/afteropenid?socketID=XXXXXX  , I create the JWT and I send it
   using the socket.io to the AngularJS open socket.

In similar questions I see that there is way of doing this by setting a cookie with the token and then making a redirect to the angularJS.

I think my approach would work and has less redirects but I am new to this and maybe I am not thinking in everything, I dont know how could this be exploited since the server only pass user info using the socket. The caveat is that the original angularJS window should remain open but that is acceptable in my situation.